# Iphone Splash Screen never goes away

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios4

I inserted a splash screen using default.png - set to one of the pictures on the desktop and now i am trying to use a view and open it that way however the last splash screen keeps appearing. Ive deleted all the code written for it and even the image. Not just removed reference but also deleted. I dont know where xcode finds the image to display it but the old image keeps appearing so i need to change it. I restarted xcode cleaned built no change. Let me know if im missing something.

Comment: Does the app actually crash or produce a crash log or display anything in the Console?

Comment: Nope. Doesnt crash it moves into the map view which i want it to do in like 3 seconds or so. I dont even have code for it to do that? although i did before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project navigator, click on the application target.  Click on the application target under Targets.  Click on the Summary tab and look at the section "iPhone / iPod Deployment Info." There you can see the launch image.  You can right-click to see the file being used in the Finder or you can delete it.

Update:   Using XCode 4.1, I was seeing problem even after deleting it using above approach.  I had to both clean the build and delete the app from device/simulator before rerunning it.

Comment: Yes that did work. I use 4.3 and even then you I had to delete it from the simulator.